Create line segments from points
I successfully coverted *.fit files to a *.sqllite database that I then imported to QGIS. I have a layer called trackpoints that I processed using Geometry by expression to create the features from lat/lng. So far so good.
I am trying to recreate a view like the following:

That is a line that can be symbolised differently based on attributes of that segment.

However all the documentation points me to use PointsToPath that creates only one line and I assume that what I need to have is multi-feature line.
How can I do that?

What are you using to convert point to line? QGIS or SQLlite Database

QGIS. I managed to use Points to Path and then Split Lines and then join by location to get attributes from the points but it seems a bit "dirty".  I thought about bringing the next point data to the current row (LEAD) to create line features but couldn't figure it out
